# Erro em busca no SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Alguém poderia me ajudar? já fiz de várias formas mas o app dá erro e fecha.
estou usando banco de dados (SQLite) quando tem que buscar dá o **erro**:

```
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226): Process: com.example.acquaconnect, PID: 12226
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18482)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3836)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    ... 11 more
0 1-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at c om.example.Banco.RepositorioClientes.buscarClientes(RepositorioClientes.java:198)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at    com.example.acquaconnect.Login.buscarClientes(Login.java:103)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    at          com.example.acquaconnect.Login.butEntrar(Login.java:37)
01-05 03:40:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12226):    ... 14 more
```

**Linha do erro (linha 37)**

```
}else if ( loginCliente.equals(buscarClientes(loginCliente))){
```

**Código**

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText vlogin;
        private EditText vsenha;
        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            vlogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextLogin);
            vsenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextSenha);
        }   


        public void butEntrar(View v) {
            String loginCliente = vlogin.getText().toString();
            String senhaCliente = vsenha.getText().toString();

            if(loginCliente.equals("") || senhaCliente.equals("")){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this ,"Campo(s) vazio(s)!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }else if ( loginCliente.equals(buscarClientes(loginCliente))){
                    Clientes c = buscarClientes(loginCliente);
                    String Login = c.login;
                    String Senha = c.senha;

                    if(senhaCliente.equals(Senha)){
                        //declaração para envio de informaçoes
                        //Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putLong("id", c.id);
                        params.putString("nivel", c.nivel);
                        params.putString("nome", c.nome);
                        params.putString("login", c.login);
                        params.putString("senha", c.senha);
                        params.putString("ncel", c.ncel);
                        params.putString("numbomba", c.numbomba);
                        params.putString("b1", c.b1);
                        params.putString("b2", c.b2);
                        params.putString("b3", c.b3);
                        params.putString("b4", c.b4);
                        params.putString("b5", c.b5);
                        params.putString("b6", c.b6);

                        //usuario
                        if(String.valueOf("1").equals(c.nivel)){
                            //mandar dados cliente---passagem de paramentros
                            //envia os dados para a prox activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Usuario.class);
                            intent.putExtras(params);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        //adm
                        else if(String.valueOf("2").equals(c.nivel)){
                                //envia os dados para a prox activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfigADM.class);
                                intent.putExtras(params);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                }/*fim if senha*/else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this ,"Login não encontrado!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    }
            }
        }//botao


        private Toast toast;
        private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
          if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Pressione novamente para sair.", 4000);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          } else {
            if (toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
          }
          super.onBackPressed();
         }
        }

        //Busca um Cliente pelo login
        public Clientes buscarClientes(String loginCliente) {
            Clientes clientes = RepositorioClientes.buscarClientes(loginCliente);
            return clientes;
        }

    }
```

**Linha do erro (linha 198)**

```
    Cursor c = db.query( NOME_TABELA, Clientes.colunas, Cliente.LOGIN + "='" + login + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

**Código**

```
public class RepositorioClientes {      

    private static final String CATEGORIA = "acqua";

    // Nome do banco
    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "acquaconnect";
    // Nome da tabela
    public static final String NOME_TABELA = "clientes";

    protected static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public RepositorioClientes(Context ctx) {
        // Abre o banco de dados já existente
        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(NOME_BANCO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    public RepositorioClientes() {
        // Apenas para criar uma subclasse...
    }

    // Salva o cliente, insere um novo ou atualiza
    public long salvar(Clientes clientes) {
        long id = clientes.id;

        if (id != 0) {
            atualizar(clientes);
        } else {
            // Insere novo
            id = inserir(clientes);
        }

        return id;
    }

    // Insere um novo Clientes
    public long inserir(Clientes clientes) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Cliente.NIVEL, clientes.nivel);
        values.put(Cliente.NOME, clientes.nome);
        values.put(Cliente.LOGIN, clientes.login);
        values.put(Cliente.SENHA, clientes.senha);
        values.put(Cliente.NCEL, clientes.ncel);
        values.put(Cliente.NUMBOMBA, clientes.numbomba);
        values.put(Cliente.B1, clientes.b1);
        values.put(Cliente.B2, clientes.b2);
        values.put(Cliente.B3, clientes.b3);
        values.put(Cliente.B4, clientes.b4);
        values.put(Cliente.B5, clientes.b5);
        values.put(Cliente.B6, clientes.b6);


        long id = inserir(values);
        return id;
    }

    // Insere um novo Clientes
    public long inserir(ContentValues valores) {
        long id = db.insert(NOME_TABELA, "", valores);
        return id;
    }

    // Atualiza o Clientes no banco. O id do Clientes é utilizado.
    public int atualizar(Clientes clientes) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Cliente.NIVEL, clientes.nivel);
        values.put(Cliente.NOME, clientes.nome);
        values.put(Cliente.LOGIN, clientes.login);
        values.put(Cliente.SENHA, clientes.senha);
        values.put(Cliente.NCEL, clientes.ncel);
        values.put(Cliente.NUMBOMBA, clientes.numbomba);
        values.put(Cliente.B1, clientes.b1);
        values.put(Cliente.B2, clientes.b2);
        values.put(Cliente.B3, clientes.b3);
        values.put(Cliente.B4, clientes.b4);
        values.put(Cliente.B5, clientes.b5);
        values.put(Cliente.B6, clientes.b6);

        String _id = String.valueOf(clientes.id);

        String where = Cliente._ID + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { _id };

        int count = atualizar(values, where, whereArgs);

        return count;
    }

    // Atualiza o cliente com os valores abaixo
    // A cláusula where é utilizada para identificar o cliente a ser atualizado
    public int atualizar(ContentValues valores, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        int count = db.update(NOME_TABELA, valores, where, whereArgs);
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, "Atualizou [" + count + "] registros");
        return count;
    }

    // Deleta o Cliente com o id fornecido
    public int deletar(long id) {
        String where = Cliente._ID + "=?";

        String _id = String.valueOf(id);
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { _id };

        int count = deletar(where, whereArgs);

        return count;
    }

    // Deleta o Cliente com os argumentos fornecidos
    public int deletar(String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        int count = db.delete(NOME_TABELA, where, whereArgs);
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, "Deletou [" + count + "] registros");
        return count;
    }


    // Retorna um cursor com todos os clientes
    public Cursor getCursor() {
        try {
            // select * from carros
            return db.query(NOME_TABELA, Clientes.colunas, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(CATEGORIA, "Erro ao buscar o cliente: " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Retorna uma lista com todos os clientes
    public List<Clientes> listarCliente() {
        Cursor c = getCursor();

        List<Clientes> cliente = new ArrayList<Clientes>();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            // Recupera os índices das colunas
            int idxId = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente._ID);
            int idxNivel = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.NIVEL);
            int idxNome = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.NOME);
            int idxLogin = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.LOGIN);
            int idxSenha = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.SENHA);
            int idxNcel = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.NCEL);
            int idxNumBomba = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.NUMBOMBA);
            int idxB1 = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.B1);
            int idxB2 = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.B2);
            int idxB3 = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.B3);
            int idxB4 = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.B4);
            int idxB5 = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.B5);
            int idxB6 = c.getColumnIndex(Cliente.B6);

            // Loop até o final
            do {
                Clientes clientes = new Clientes();
                cliente.add(clientes);

                // recupera os atributos de cliente
                clientes.id = c.getLong(idxId);
                clientes.nivel = c.getString(idxNivel);
                clientes.nome = c.getString(idxNome);
                clientes.login = c.getString(idxLogin);
                clientes.senha = c.getString(idxSenha);
                clientes.ncel = c.getString(idxNcel);
                clientes.numbomba = c.getString(idxNumBomba);
                clientes.b1 = c.getString(idxB1);
                clientes.b2 = c.getString(idxB2);
                clientes.b3 = c.getString(idxB3);
                clientes.b4 = c.getString(idxB4);
                clientes.b5 = c.getString(idxB5);
                clientes.b6 = c.getString(idxB6);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return cliente;
    }

    // Busca o cliente pelo login "select * from cliente where nome=?" MODIFICANDOO
    public static Clientes buscarClientes(String login) {
        Clientes clientes = null;

        try {
            // Idem a: SELECT _id,nivel,nome,login,senha,ncel,numbomba,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6 from CARRO where login = ?
            Cursor c = db.query( NOME_TABELA, Clientes.colunas, Cliente.LOGIN + "='" + login + "'", null, null, null, null);

            // Se encontrou...
            if (c.moveToNext()) {

                clientes = new Clientes();

                // utiliza os métodos getLong(), getString(), getInt(), etc para recuperar os valores
                clientes.id = c.getLong(0);
                clientes.nivel = c.getString(1);
                clientes.nome = c.getString(2);
                clientes.login = c.getString(3);
                clientes.senha = c.getString(4);
                clientes.ncel = c.getString(5);
                clientes.numbomba = c.getString(6);
                clientes.b1 = c.getString(7);
                clientes.b2 = c.getString(8);
                clientes.b3 = c.getString(9);
                clientes.b4 = c.getString(10);
                clientes.b5 = c.getString(11);
                clientes.b6 = c.getString(12);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(CATEGORIA, "Erro ao buscar o cliente" + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        return clientes;
    }

    // Busca o carro pelo id
    public Clientes buscarClientesporID(long id) {
            // select * from carro where _id=?
            Cursor c = db.query(true, NOME_TABELA, Clientes.colunas, Cliente._ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {

                // Posicinoa no primeiro elemento do cursor
                c.moveToFirst();

                Clientes clientes = new Clientes();

                // Lê os dados
                clientes.id = c.getLong(0);
                clientes.nivel = c.getString(1);
                clientes.nome = c.getString(2);
                clientes.login = c.getString(3);
                clientes.senha = c.getString(4);
                clientes.ncel = c.getString(5);
                clientes.numbomba = c.getString(6);
                clientes.b1 = c.getString(7);
                clientes.b2 = c.getString(8);
                clientes.b3 = c.getString(9);
                clientes.b4 = c.getString(10);
                clientes.b5 = c.getString(11);
                clientes.b6 = c.getString(12);

                return clientes;
            }

            return null;
        }

    // Busca um carro utilizando as configurações definidas no
    // SQLiteQueryBuilder
    // Utilizado pelo Content Provider de carro
    public Cursor query(SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(this.db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        return c;
    }

    // Fecha o banco
    public void fechar() {
        // fecha o banco de dados
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Segundo seu *stack trace*, o erro está na linha `198` do arquivo `RepositorioClientes.java`, método `com.example.Banco.RepositorioClientes.buscarClientes`. Por favor poste o código desse método, indicando qual é a linha 198, assim saberemos exatamente qual variável está com valor nulo e o que pode estar causando isso. (P.S. se possível indique também qual é a linha `37` do `butEntrar`, pois esta é quem chama `buscarClientes`)

Comment: Você chegou a chamar o construtor de `RepositorioClientes` em algum momento? Eu noto que o campo estático `db` é nulo até que alguém chame o construtor passando um `Context`, e se isso não for feito antes de se chamar `RepositorioClientes.buscarClientes` isso seria uma das possíveis causas do seu erro (as demais sendo `Clientes` nulo ou `Cliente` nulo - o que não faz muito sentido). Independentemente disso, na minha opinião `db` e `buscarClientes` não deveriam ser estáticos, e sim membros da instância...

Comment: não chamei o construtor não... vou dar uma olhada nesses pontos aqui então.

Comment: Tip:  Use Ormlite framework
http://ormlite.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Java, uma exceção pode causar outra, esta causar outra, etc, de modo que é necessário buscar pela causa raiz do erro. No *stack trace* isso é mostrado via `Caused by: ...`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ...
```

A origem está então na última exceção exibida (a primeira ocorrida). Cada linha da mesma mostra em que linha de código o problema ocorreu, da "mais funda" pra "mais rasa" (i.e. se o método `a` chamou `b` que chamou `c` que lançou uma exceção, será mostrado primeiro `c` depois `b` depois `a`). Como raramente o problema está na própria linguagem e/ou suas bibliotecas, procure sempre por uma linha que você escreveu.

Infelizmente, muitas vezes o *stack trace* vem truncado, mas nesse caso a linha onde a exceção ocorreu (a do topo) é uma que você escreveu:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.Banco.RepositorioClientes.buscarClientes(RepositorioClientes.java:198)
```

Isso indica que ocorreu um erro de referência nula **exatamente** nessa linha, não em um código chamado por ela, não em alguém que chama ela. Observando a linha em questão:

```
Cursor c = db.query( NOME_TABELA, Clientes.colunas, Cliente.LOGIN + "='" + login + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

nota-se há três possibilidades somente: ou `db` é nulo, ou `Clientes` é nulo ou `Cliente` é nulo. Assumindo que estes dois últimos são classes, e não variáveis (pela convenção de capitalização), provavelmente o problema está em `db`.

No restante do seu código, noto que `db` é um campo estático (i.e. de classe) de `RepositorioClientes`, mas sua única atribuição é feita durante a chamada de seu construtor. Em alguns casos isso pode ser interessante (inicialização preguiçosa de um objeto global, por exemplo) mas em geral é uma má prática - pois se o campo é estático ele não deveria depender da criação de nenhuma instância em particular. Mais: se duas instâncias forem criadas uma após a outra, o campo `db` será sobrescrito durante a segunda chamada do construtor, **sem que a primeira tenha sido fechada**, o que pode vir a provocar um vazamento de memória.

Minha sugestão é torná-lo um campo de instância (i.e. não estático), de modo que uma referência para `RepositorioClientes` seja necessária para acessá-lo:

```
public class RepositorioClientes {      
    ...
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

...

RepositorioClientes rep = new RepositorioCliente(ctx);
try {
    rep.buscarClientes(str); // Também passa a ser um método de instância
}
finally {
    rep.fechar(); // Só um exemplo: feche a conexão só quando ela não for mais necessária
}
```

Dessa forma não haverá o risco de um `NullPointerException`, pois todo objeto `RepositorioClientes` terá uma instância de `db` garantidamente criada (pelo construtor). O máximo que pode acontecer é ela ter sido previamente fechada - caso em que também ocorreria um erro, só que diferente.

Comment: +1 pela explicação sobre a ordem no StackTrace, eu desconhecia. =)